# ошибка при компиляции(Ошибка LNK2019)

Tags: c++

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl SortTravelersList(struct Travelers * *,int (__cdecl*)(struct Travelers *,struct Travelers *))" (?SortTravelersList@@YAXPAPAUTravelers@@P6AHPAU1@1@Z@Z) в функции _main.

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    struct Travelers
    {
        int ticket_code;
        string lastname;
        int numberofthings;
        int luggage_weight;
        Travelers* Next;
    };
    
    Travelers* Head = 0;
    struct Date {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        Date* Next;
    };
    Date* Head2 = 0;
    struct Date2 {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        Date* Next;
    };
    Date* Head3 = 0;
    void Insert_Traveler(Travelers** list, Travelers* t, unsigned int pos)
    {
        if (pos == 0 || *list == 0) {
            t->Next = *list;
            *list = t;
        }
        else if (pos == 0) {
            t->Next = *list;
            *list = t;
        }
        else {
            Travelers* p = *list;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
                if (i == pos - 1)
                    break;
            t->Next = p->Next;
            p->Next = t;
        }
    }
    Travelers* Choose_Travelers(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos)
    {
        while (list && pos)
        {
            list = list->Next;
            --pos;
        }
    
        return list;
    }
    Travelers* Choose_NextAndBefore1(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos) {
        return Choose_Travelers(list, pos + 1);
    }
    Travelers* Choose_NextAndBefore2(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos) {
        return Choose_Travelers(list, pos - 1);
    }
    int Location(Travelers* list, string key) {
        Travelers* p = list;
        unsigned int n = 0;
        for (; p; n++, p = p->Next) {
            if (p->lastname == key) break;
        }
        return n;
    }
    Travelers* Delete_Traveler(Travelers** list, unsigned int pos)
    {
        Travelers* d = 0;
    
        if (pos == 0) {
            d = *list;
            *list = d->Next;
        }
        else {
            Travelers* p = *list;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
                if (i == pos - 1) {
                    d = p->Next;
                    p->Next = d->Next;
                    break;
                }
        }
    
        return d;
    }
    
    void Print_Travelers(Travelers* list)
    {
        for (Travelers* p = list; p; p = p->Next)
            cout << "code: " << p->ticket_code
            << "  " << p->lastname
            << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
        cout << '\n';
    }
    void Print_Date(Date* list) {
        for (Date* p = list; p; p = p->Next)
            cout << "day: " << p->day
            << " month: " << p->month
            << " year: " << p->year
            << '\n';
        cout << '\n';
    }
    void Unite_Date(Date* head1, Date* head2)
    {
        Date* p = head1;
        while (p->Next != NULL)
            p = p->Next;
        p->Next = head2;
    }
    Date* Find_Date(Date* list, size_t pos)
    {
        if (pos == 0 || !list)
            return list;
    
        while (list->Next && pos)
        {
            list = list->Next;
            --pos;
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    void Insert_Date(Date** list, Date* pos, Date* item)
    {
        if (!pos)
        {
            item->Next = *list;
            *list = item;
        }
        else
        {
            item->Next = pos->Next;
            pos->Next = item;
        }
    }
    
    void Insert_Date(Date** list, Date* t, size_t pos)
    {
        Insert_Date(list, Find_Date(*list, pos), t);
    }
    void SortTravelersList(Travelers** list, int (*cmpf)(Travelers* s1, Travelers* s2));
    int cmpf_ticket(Travelers* s1, Travelers* s2) {
        return s1->ticket_code - s2->ticket_code;
    }
    
    int cmpf_lastname(Travelers* s1, Travelers* s2) {
        int rc = 0;
        if (s1->lastname < s2->lastname)
            rc = -1;
        else if (s1->lastname > s2->lastname)
            rc = 1;
        return rc;
    }
    int main()
    {
    
        Date* q = new Date;
        q->day = rand() % 30;
        q->month = rand() % 12;
        q->year = 2021;
        Insert_Date(&Head2, q, 1);
        Print_Date(Head2);
        Date* w = new Date;
        w->day = rand() % 30;
        w->month = rand() % 12;
        w->year = 2021;
        Insert_Date(&Head3, w, 1);
        Print_Date(Head3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            char nm[10];
            Travelers* p = new Travelers;
            p->ticket_code = rand() % 1000;
            sprintf_s(nm, "tr_%d", i);
            p->lastname = nm;
            p->numberofthings = rand() % 5 + 1;
            p->luggage_weight = (rand() % 10 + 1) * p->numberofthings;
    
            Insert_Traveler(&Head, p, i);
        }
    
        cout << "list of travelers\n";
        Print_Travelers(Head);
    
        cout << "delete some travelers\n";
        Travelers* p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, 9);
        if (p) {
            cout << "delete as pos " << 9 << "  "
                << "code: " << p->ticket_code
                << "  " << p->lastname
                << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
                << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
                << '\n';
            delete p;
        }
    
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, i);
            if (p) {
                cout << "delete as pos " << i << "  "
                    << "code: " << p->ticket_code
                    << "  " << p->lastname
                    << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
                    << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
                    << '\n';
                delete p;
            }
        }
    
        cout << "------\n";
        cout << "\nlist of travelers after deletions\n";
        Print_Travelers(Head);
        int pos;
        cout << "Choose index" << endl;
        cin >> pos;
        Travelers* k = Choose_Travelers(Head, pos);
        if (!k)
            std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            cout << "code: " << k->ticket_code
                << "  " << k->lastname
                << " nth: " << k->numberofthings
                << " weight: " << k->luggage_weight
                << '\n';
        }
        cout << "Enter a key you want to choose" << endl;
        string key;
        cin >> key;
        int t = Location(Head, key);
        cout << t << endl;
        int poss;
        cout << "Choose index" << endl;
        cin >> poss;
        Travelers* e = Choose_NextAndBefore1(Head, poss);
        if (!e)
            std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            cout << "code: " << e->ticket_code
                << "  " << e->lastname
                << " nth: " << e->numberofthings
                << " weight: " << e->luggage_weight
                << '\n';
        }
        Travelers* b = Choose_NextAndBefore2(Head, poss);
        if (!b)
            std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            cout << "code: " << b->ticket_code
                << "  " << b->lastname
                << " nth: " << b->numberofthings
                << " weight: " << b->luggage_weight
                << '\n';
        }
        Unite_Date(Head2, Head3);
        Print_Date(Head2);
        SortTravelersList(&Head, cmpf_ticket);
        Print_Travelers(Head);
    }
```

Comment: А писать код этой функции кто будет? Дейкстра?...

Comment: Ваша ссылка на все вопросы опять не в тему. Там нет объяснения, что функции с одним именем, но с другим набором/типов аргументов они разные, по-этому такой функции с двумя аргументами не нашлось. @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe Выделяю `SortTravelersList`, делаю поиск по странице, вижу два - в сообщении об ошибке, одно - в объявлении функции, одно - в вызове. Что я не так написал? Где код этой функции? который я не заметил?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Да где же? Вот объявление - `void SortTravelersList(Travelers** list, int (*cmpf)(Travelers* s1, Travelers* s2));` - два аргумента, вот вызов - `SortTravelersList(&Head, cmpf_ticket);` - тоже два. В вашем варианте не прошла бы **компиляция**, а тут - не идет **ликновка**

Comment: Всё правильно, я проглядел. `dada dasda` уже хочет, чтобы мы всё написали. @Harry